# Apache Wink integration with Spring

Tags: spring

I am trying to integrate Apache wink 1.4 with Spring on JBoss EAP 6.4. Below is my Pom.xml excerpt.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
        <artifactId>wink-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
        <artifactId>wink-spring-support</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
        <artifactId>wink-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
    <artifactId>wink-json4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.archetype.eap</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee6-webapp-archetype</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0.GA</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I also have configuration in web.xml to look for winkdefault.properties.

[image]

While building the application, It is not able to find the "META-INF/wink-default.properties" I am getting following exception in server log.

[org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/wink-default1.properties]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/wink-default.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Could anyone help on this please ?

Comment: I decompiled wink-spring-support.jar and changed context with following classpath:META-INF/server/wink-core-context.xml and it was able to register.

Answer (score 0):

I decompiled wink-spring-support.jar and changed context with following classpath:META-INF/server/wink-core-context.xml and it was able to register.